# PHP: String to full ASCII

Tags: php

I'm using an RTF converter and I need `240` as `&#U050&#U052&#U048` but Im not to sure how to do this!?!

I have tried using the following function:

```
function string_to_ascii($string) {
    $ascii = NULL;
    for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($string); $i++) {
            $ascii += "&#U"+str_pad(ord($string[$i]),3,"0",STR_PAD_LEFT);
    }
    return($ascii);
}
```

But it still just outputs just the number (e.g. `2` = `50`) and `ord` just makes it go mad.

I've tried `echo "-&#U"+ord("2")+"-";` and I get `50416` !?!?

I have a feeling it might have something to do with encoding

Comment: `&#U050` is not ASCII. It's an XML/HTML numeric entity, using unicode encoding. Anyway, what kind of insane software needs plain text characters to be entity encoded like that?

Comment: http://www.paggard.com/projects/rtf.generator/ :(

Comment: Hmmm, well, I've not used it, but a quick scan of the documentation only mentions using entities for non ASCII symbols like `©`. And other examples seem to use plain text. As I say I've not used it, so if it really does need all that encoding then so be it, but I'd be very surprised.

Comment: I know. When I use a `£` I have to use `&#U163`. It then won't let me use numbers or letters after it (I suppose till it hits a space). So `240` becomes `&#U050&#U052&#U048` :(

Comment: Entity codes are supposed to end with a semi-colon -- ie `&#U163;`. That's how it knows it's finished the entity. Add a semi-colon to the end of your entities, and it let you use numbers and letters after it just fine.

Comment: I was wondering why I had to carry on using ASCII. Cheers :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're over thinking this. Convert the string to an array with [`str_split`](http://php.net/str_split), [map](http://php.net/array_map) [`ord`](http://php.net/ord) to all of it, then if you want to format each one, use [`sprintf`](http://php.net/sprintf) (or [`str_pad`](http://php.net/str_pad) if you'd like), like this:

```
function string_to_ascii($string) {
    $array = array_map( 'ord', str_split( $string));
    // Optional formatting:
    foreach( $array as $k => &$v) {
        $v = sprintf( "%03d", $v);
    }
    return "&#U" . implode( "&#U", $array);
}
```

Now, when you pass `string_to_ascii( '240')`, you get back `string(18) "&#U050&#U052&#U048"`.

Answer (score 0):

Just found this:

```
function to_ascii($string) {
    $ascii_string = '';
    foreach (str_split($string) as $char) {
        $ascii_string .= '&#' . ord($char) . ';';
    }
    return $ascii_string;
}
```

[here](http://snipplr.com/view/23796/)